SwiftUI - Prevent open new window as a Tab
I use the following code to open a new window with SwiftUI on macOS:
@main
struct ComponentsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestView()
        }
        
        WindowGroup(id: "test") {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("open") {
            self.openWindow(id: "test")
        }
    }
}

In my system settings I have enabled, that new windows should always open as a tab. So my application does the same. I would like to have the possibility to tell SwiftUI, not to tab the windows. Is this possible?

Are you actually looking for answers to this? It seems you posted your own answer immediately after posting the question.

I wanted to share my answer if someone has the same problem.

As far as I can see, it is actually not possible to set the tabbingMode with SwiftUI. So I used this:
struct WindowNoTab: NSViewRepresentable {
        
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        Task { @MainActor in
            view.window?.tabbingMode = .disallowed
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
extension View {
    func noTabWindow() -> some View {
        self
            .background(WindowNoTab())
    }
}

If you then modify your view in the WindowGroup, the windows will not be tabbed anymore:
struct ComponentsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TestView()
        }
        
        WindowGroup(id: "test") {
            Text("Test")
                .noTabWindow()
        }
    }
}

